# How to resolve the .mo file path for translation?

Tags: php, mysql, locale, poedit, multiple-languages

I'm trying to set my website in several languages. I'm using Poedit and .mo files. .mo files are ready and I'm adding the configuration necessary but it doesn't works. For understand my problem, please look the image.

[image]

When I load the page in the language es_LA, it still to be in English. What I'm doing wrong?

(Comment in the image fix: Suposing the path will be ./lang/es_LA/LC_MESSAGES/crishk.mo)

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindtextdomain.php says to use "_The full pathname for the domain currently being set._"

Comment: I get: F:\project\lang\ as path!!!! :(